# Combinations for a team with different roles

Tags: combinatorics

I want to calculate the number of possible combinations for a team with a number N people who has "role". I'll give an example: Let's say we're playing soccer where N = 10 and everyone can play every role (Goalkeeper, defense and attack). Then we can calculate the # of combinations with: $ \Omega(N) = \dfrac{N!}{2\cdot((\frac{N}{2})!)^2}$. We would find that $\Omega(10) = 126$.

But what if everyone couldn't play every role. For example what if 2 players only played goalkeeper. How would that affect the # of combinations? Furthermore what if someone could play 2 out 3 roles? It's possible to do this with manually but it is rather tedious so I was wondering if there was a way to generalize this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your equation for $\Omega(N)$.  It looks like you are selecting half the players for one team, then dividing by $2$ because you can switch the two teams.  Your description does not seem to match this unless you are playing five a side and no paying attention to people's positions on the team.  Nice formulas come from symmetry of the problem.  As you break the symmetry it becomes more complicated quickly.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry I should have been more specific. $\Omega(N)$ Describes the number of every possible match with 10 people who can play every role.  The reasoning for dividing becomes clear with an example: We have players a,b,c,d. We can have 3 possible matches: a+b vs c+d, a+c vs b+d, vs a+d vs b+c. Without dividing by 2, we would every team but I'm interested in the number of matches thus the 2. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: But then if you have somebody who can fill 2 of 3 roles, or even 1 of 3, it doesn't change the number of team possibilities.  You only change that when you have too many restricted people, like two who can only play goalie.  Then they can't be on the same team.

Comment: Yes that is true, but I'm curious as to how it affects $\Omega(N)$ when there are too many restricted people.

Comment: Because there are so many possibilities for the restrictions and the ways they interact, there isn't a nice formula.  You have to consider a certain set of restrictions.